# Need to update tool tip value based on drop down filter after ajax call

Tags: jquery, chart.js

Need to update tool tip value based on drop down filter after Ajax call

How do I update "ChartJs" tooltip to add dropdown filter calculated value in tooltip.

```
addData (clientChart, Object.keys(objClient), Object.values(objClient));
addData (productChart, Object.keys(objProduct), Object.values(objProduct));
addData (departmentChart, Object.keys(objDepartment), Object.values(objDepartment));
addData (weekChart, Object.keys(objWeek), Object.values(objWeek));

function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels = label;
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data = data;
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

Above code is "ChartJs" function to update dataset but need to update options tooltips label, beforeLabel and afterLabel value. I have updated values of label, beforeLabel and afterLabel in json object.

I did not found anything in "ChartJs" docs about this. Am I doing something wrong or this is impossible with this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got Solution in "ChartJs" doc

function updateConfigAsNewObject(chart) {
    chart.options = {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Chart.js'
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: true
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                display: true
            }]
        }
    };
    chart.update();
}